# Probability of forming a Triangle from $3$ integer point whose area is positive.

Tags: probability

> 

Let $\displaystyle  X = [ ( x , y ) \in Z\times Z,\frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{y^2}{20}<1,y^2<5x]$ Three distinct point $P, Q$ and $R$ are randomly chosen from $X$. Then the probability that $P, Q$ and $R$ form a triangle whose area is a positive integer.

First we will draw graph of $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{8}+\frac{y^2}{20}<1$ and $y^2<5x$

So all integer ordered which satisfy $(1,0),(2,0),(1,\pm 1),(1,\pm 2),(2,\pm 1),(2,\pm 2),(2,\pm 3)$

[image]

So we have total $12$ points, Then

Total ways $\displaystyle \binom{12}{3}=220$

And for favourable point

$\displaystyle \binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{7}{1}+\binom{5}{1}\cdot \binom{7}{2}=175$

But my favourable cases are not correct  , in answer favourable cases are $73$

Please have a look on that problem

Comment: Do you consider that the area had to be a positive integer? It seems to me that you just found triangles.

Comment: I have noted that lot many of the questions you ask are also there in former question papers of JEE Advanced, such as this one. Many solutions to the same are available online on other websites too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's error that they merely counted the number of cases where $PQR$ has positive area.

Because $PQR$ also needs an area that is an integer, since the height in the x-direction is always 1, this means that the base in the y-direction must be a multiple of 2.

Hence, the number of cases is

$$ [ { 3 \choose 2 } + { 2 \choose 2} ] \times 7 + [ { 4 \choose 2 } + { 3 \choose 2} ] \times 5 = 73 . $$

Comment: +1: you beat me by 2 minutes!